# Neo4J with APOC and MongoDB Driver, limiting returned records from Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Limiting the number of returned records in MongoDB is as simple as
`db.collection.find().limit(n)`. 
However I'd like to issue the equivalent query from Neo4J.

Given that a find query is issued from Neo4J as follows...
`apoc.mongodb.find(host, db, collection, query, project, sort)`
I find it difficult to see how one should tell the MongoDB instance to limit the returned results before streaming to Neo4J.

I am aware of Cypher's LIMIT clause, however, this feels like bad practice, considering the amount of redundant data that will be streamed from Mongo.

Is there yet a way of adding a limit to the query results pre-stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this is not available out of the box. But you can add this functionality.

In the [APOC source code](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) make the following changes:

`neo4j-apoc-procedures/src/main/java/apoc/mongodb/MongoDB.java`:

---

```
@Procedure
@Description("apoc.mongodb.find(host-or-port,db-or-null,collection-or-null,query-or-null,projection-or-null,sort-or-null,[compatibleValues=true|false]) yield value - perform a find,project,sort operation on mongodb collection")
public Stream<MapResult> find(@Name("host") String hostOrKey, @Name("db") String db, @Name("collection") String collection, @Name("query") Map<String, Object> query, @Name("project") Map<String, Object> project, @Name("sort") Map<String, Object> sort, @Name(value = "compatibleValues", defaultValue = "false") boolean compatibleValues) {
    return getMongoColl(hostOrKey, db, collection, compatibleValues).find(query, project, sort).map(MapResult::new);
}
```

---

```
interface Coll extends Closeable {

...

    Stream<Map<String, Object>> find(Map<String, Object> query, Map<String, Object> project, Map<String, Object> sort, Map<String, Object> pagination);
```

---

`neo4j-apoc-procedures/src/main/java/apoc/mongodb/MongoDBColl.java`:

---

```
@Override
public Stream<Map<String, Object>> find(Map<String, Object> query, Map<String, Object> project, Map<String, Object> sort, Map<String, Object> pagination) {
    FindIterable<Document> documents = query == null ? collection.find() : collection.find(new Document(query));
    if (project != null) documents = documents.projection(new Document(project));
    if (sort != null) documents = documents.sort(new Document(sort));
    if (pagination != null) {
        Object skip = pagination.get("skip");
        Object limit = pagination.get("limit");
        if (skip != null) documents = documents.skip(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(skip)));
        if (limit != null) documents = documents.limit(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(limit)));
    }
    return asStream(documents);
}
```